# Getting exact maximum daily temperature using remote sensing?

Tags: remote-sensing, landsat, heat-map, surface

I have a problem I want to find the land surface temperature of Bangkok using landsat8.

I have everything to get it but the problem is landsat images are obtained during morning time but the maximum temperature will be afternoon period.

How can I get the exact maximum temperatures of a day?

Answer (score 3):

Sun synchronous satellites like Landsat always capture an image at the same time of the day. Furthermore, Landsat "only" repeats its acquisitions every 16 days.

If you want an image in the afternoon, MODIS AQUA has a daily coverage at 1.30 PM, which is a better timing but at a lower spatial resolution (500m).

Finally, you can get the highest temporal resolution with geostationnary satellites like [METEOSAT-5 MVIRI](http://www.wmo-sat.info/oscar/instruments/view/337), but then you have a spatial resolution of 5 km.

As you can see, the best spatial and temporal resolutions never come together.

As a last remark, land surface temperature is not a direct measurement of the temperature of the air but depends on the emissivity of the observed land cover. This has to be taken into account for some applications.

Comment: Sir, I am doing work on Bangkok which is small area  only so MODIS and METEOSAT data is not useful for me. So can you suggest me which data is useful

Comment: AS far as I know, you need too much precision to rely on remote sensing: Only geostationnary satellites give you more than one image/day at this latitude, and they are much coarser. Maybe there is a network of meteo stations that could help you.

Comment: Yeah I have the data of meteo station but the main thing I want to find the lst using remote sensing and then take the meteo station data and want correlate both ....so I am confused

Comment: As far as I understand, you need a combination of high temporal resolution (for daily max you need several images per day) and high spatial resolution on a satellite with thermal band (100 m with Landsat TIR bands before resampling)  : this is currently NOT available as far as I know (maybe some secret satellite constellation...).